# How to stop calculating if there're some large number?

Tags: warning-messages, big-numbers

I want to calculate something like `o[n, o[n, o[n, n]]]`

Where `n` means a number and `o` means a operation.

During the  calculation process there are some very large numbers and they are meaningless for me.

Just stop calculating and return `Indeterminate`.

In fact Mathematica will Automatic abort and throw error `Throw::sysexc`, that means out of memory and **the results all disappear**.

```
In []:= pattern=o[2,o[2,o[8,13]]];
        tps=Tuples[{Plus,Subtract,Times,Divide,Power,Log,#1^(1/#2)&},3];
        ReplacePart[pattern,Thread[Position[pattern,o]->#]]&/@tps
Out[]:= SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]`
```

Is there any way to solve this with some settings?

I don't want to reconstruct my functions.

```
upBound=10^10;lowBound=1/upBound;
With/Block[{...},
    .............
    myFun/@myList
]
```

Comment: You could try using `MemoryConstrained`

Comment: It's hard to estimate how much memory a particular step needs.

Comment: Perhaps, `NestWhile` would be helpful, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Well, that pattern just an example...also can be something like `o[o[o[n, n], n], o[n, n]]`...

Comment: I think there is a problem with the strategy sought in the question: For instance `8^13` really isn't that big (it's a machine-size integer), but `2^(8^13)` crashes my kernel -- I don't even get the  `Throw::sysexc` error.  So I never found out that the number was too large before the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another way that implements a numeric check on the size of the result, somewhat like what the OP asked for.  The trick is to compute the result first in floating-point.  If it's in some range, then proceed with the exact computation.  This can be done with a simple helper wrapper:

```
ClearAll[numChk];
numChk[op_][x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] /; 
   10^-1000 < Abs@op[N@x, N@y] < 10^1000 := op[x, y];  (* adjust range as desired *)

res = ReplacePart[pattern, Thread[Position[pattern, o] -> #]] & /@ 
   Map[numChk, tps, {2}];
```

On a valid result, [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ.html) will return `True`.
Here is a way to see all the computations that failed:

```
DeleteCases[res, _?NumericQ]
(*
{numChk[Plus][2, numChk[Power][2, 549755813888]], 
 numChk[Subtract][2, numChk[Power][2, 549755813888]], 
 numChk[Times][2, numChk[Power][2, 549755813888]], 
 numChk[Divide][2, numChk[Power][2, 549755813888]], 
 numChk[Power][2, 549755813890], numChk[Power][2, -549755813886], 
 numChk[Power][2, 1099511627776], numChk[Power][2, 2097152], 
 numChk[Power][2, 20282409603651670423947251286016], 
 numChk[Power][2, numChk[Power][2, 549755813888]], 
 numChk[Log][2, numChk[Power][2, 549755813888]], 
 numChk[#1^(1/#2) &][2, 1/274877906944], 
 numChk[#1^(1/#2) &][2, numChk[Power][2, 549755813888]]}
*)
```

Sometimes the computation fails at the last `op`, sometimes at the second-to-last `op` in the test example.

If you use `DeleteCases[res, _?NumericQ] /. numChk -> Inactive`, you get a nicer-looking list of failures:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These are the same failures as in my other answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way, using Carl Woll's suggestion of [`MemoryConstrained`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemoryConstrained.html), which runs very quickly:

```
Do[
 ans[t] = 
  MemoryConstrained[
   ReplacePart[pattern, Thread[Position[pattern, o] -> t]], 
   8*^9,         (* depending on how much memory you have *)
   $Failed[t]],
 {t, tps}
 ]
```

> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.

You can do this with `Map` instead of `Do`, but `Map` would store up the results in addition to storing the result in `ans[#]`.  If some answers were big, it would waste memory.

Here's how to see which failed:

```
Cases[DownValues@ans, _[_, _$Failed]]
(*
{HoldPattern[ans[{Divide, Power, Power}]] :> $Failed[t], 
 HoldPattern[ans[{Log, Power, Power}]] :> $Failed[t], 
 HoldPattern[ans[{Plus, Power, Power}]] :> $Failed[t], 
 HoldPattern[ans[{Power, Plus, Power}]] :> $Failed[t], 
 HoldPattern[ans[{Power, Power, Power}]] :> $Failed[t], 
 HoldPattern[ans[{Power, Subtract, Power}]] :> $Failed[t], 
 HoldPattern[ans[{Power, Times, Power}]] :> $Failed[t], 
 HoldPattern[ans[{Subtract, Power, Power}]] :> $Failed[t], 
 HoldPattern[ans[{Times, Power, Power}]] :> $Failed[t], 
 HoldPattern[ans[{#1^(1/#2) &, Divide, Power}]] :> $Failed[t], 
 HoldPattern[ans[{#1^(1/#2) &, Power, Power}]] :> $Failed[t]}
*)
```

Perhaps you can figure out a way to deal with some of them, perhaps doing one operation at a time instead of substituting for all three `o` at once.

All 343 answers, including failures may be obtained with the following:

```
Values@ DownValues@ ans
```

This should give the same answer as the original code, if it worked.  If you want them with the tuples, as in the failures above, omit the `Values@`.  Failures may be deleted with [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html), which works like `Cases`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Throw`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Throw.html) and [`Catch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catch.html) with a helper function in [`FoldPair`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldPair.html) to stop calculating when the intermediate result is outside of `lowBound <= x <= upBound`

First a helper function for `FoldList` that performs the replacement and returns both the resulting expression and the expression (value) at the position of the replacement.

```
ClearAll[replacePartValue];
replacePartValue[expr_, r : pos_ -> new_, b : {lower_, upper_}] :=
 {
    With[{v = #[[Sequence @@ Most@pos]]},
     If[lower <= v <= upper,
      v,
      Throw[Indeterminate]
      ]],
    #
    } &@ReplacePart[expr, pos -> new]
```

Giving

```
replacePartValue[pattern, {2, 2, 0} -> Plus]
```

> ```
> {21, o[2, o[2, 21]]}
> ```

`replacePartValue` also takes the upper and lower bounds to check if the result at the position of the replacement is within bounds.  If it is not then it `Throw`s [`Indeterminate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indeterminate.html).

For the bounds check to work the replacements must occur at the deepest levels first and then work upward to the most shallow levels. At the same time the ordinal location of the placeholders (`o`) must match to the ordinal locations of the functions in the `tps` list.  Therefore, the positions and functions must be paired first and then [`Reverse`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reverse.html) [`SortBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html)ed the [`First`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html) element in the pair (the position) before [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)ing [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) to the pairs for use in [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html). This logic is the third argument in `FoldPair` below.

Finally `FoldPair` is wrapped in `Catch` to capture any `Throw`s from `replacePartValue`. This is mapped across `tps`.

With `pattern` and `tps` as defined in OP and

```
pos = Position[pattern, o]
```

Then

```
res =
  Catch[
     FoldPair[
      replacePartValue[#1, #2, {lowBound, upBound}] &,
      pattern,
      Rule @@@ Reverse@SortBy[First]@Thread@{pos, #}
      ]] & /@ tps ;

(*First 5*)
res[[;; 5]]
```

> ```
> {25, Indeterminate, 108, 60/13, Indeterminate}
> ```

Hope this helps.